# Scala Form Formatter for accepting JSON values

Tags: json, forms, scala, validation, playframework-2.0

I am trying to achieve the following.

```
val form = Form(
    mapping(
      "stream-name" -> nonEmptyText(minLength = 1),
      "query" -> optional(nonEmptyText),
      "input-stream" -> of(JsArray),
      "archive-ttlsec" -> optional(longNumber),
      "sample-rate" -> optional(of(play.api.data.format.Formats.doubleFormat)),
      "sample-size" -> optional(number),
    )(Data.apply)(Data.unapply)
  )

case class Data(
  `stream-name`: String,
  query: Option[String],
  `input-stream`: JsArray,
  `archive-ttlsec`: Option[Long] = None,
  `sample-rate`: Option[Double] = None,
  `sample-size`: Option[Int] = None,
)
```

This is a Scala Form data validator that I have created with

> "input-stream" -> of(JsArray)

Form is not able to validate this and is giving

> Type Mismatch, expected: Formatter[NonInferedT] actual: JsArray.type

Any workaround for this?

Comment: Your `input-stream` type - why do you have it typed to a JsArray and not something more Specific ?

Comment: Play Forms are not magic and they do not have support for everything that you want. You just can not write `of(ABCDEF)` and expect it to work. If you need a `form mapper` for `JsArray`, you will have to implement it. Or you can change your `input-stream` from `JsArray` to `list(text)` and then use this `list` to create your `JsArray`.